# Javascript bookmarklet to send url of current page to bing

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

A bookmarklet is a bookmark whose address is JavaScript code.

I would like to get the URL of the current page I am on and paste that into the text box of the Bing search page.

I can get the URL easily enough:

```
javascript:(function(){var%20url=window.location.href;alert(url);})();
```

But then how do I set the text box on the Bing page to my variable, `url` and then make it search?

This does not work:

```
javascript:(function(){var%20url=window.location.href;window.open%20("https://www.bing.com/search?q=&url");})();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following bookmarklet code:

```
javascript:{window.location='http://bing.com/search?q='+encodeURIComponent(window.location.href)}
```

Comment: thank you. I tried using the same code for another site name 'whoishostingthis' with the following code:    `javascript:{window.location='http://www.whoishostingthis.com/search?q='+encodeURIComponent(window.location.href)}`  but it fails. I know I am asking another question in the same thread but it seems closely related.

Comment: @acquagremlin Since you have asked, the correct code is this  `javascript:{window.location='https://www.whoishostingthis.com/?q='+encodeURIComponent(window.location.href)}`

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do the way you have seen above. However, I have been in this situation where I wanted to control what to show from within my application.

Then I decided to connect my application from Bing API. The benefit is that it is free and you will not take user away from your website.

You will need to get the API Key from the Azure Market Place

Here is the code that you might want to give it a try , may be, in the future.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>BING API Integration</title>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


$(function() {
    $('#searchButton').click(function(e){
        $("#results").empty();
        var query=$('#searchTerm').val();
        if ( query) {
            serviceOp = "Web";
            search(query, serviceOp);
        }
    });
});

function search(query, serviceOp){


    // your account key that youw ill get from https://datamarket.azure.com
    var acctKey = '<Your Key>';

    var rootUri = 'https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search';

    var requestUri = rootUri + "/" + serviceOp + "?$format=json&Query='" + query + "'";


    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: requestUri,
        headers: {
        "Authorization": "Basic " + window.btoa(acctKey  + ":" + acctKey)
        },

    }).done(function(o){

        if ( o.d !== undefined){
                var items = o.d.results;
                    for(var idx=0, len= items.length; idx < len; idx++ ){
                        var item = items[idx];
                        switch(item.__metadata.type){
                            case 'WebResult':
                            showWebResult(item);
                        }
                    }
                }
    });
}

// Shows one item of Web result.

function showWebResult(item) {

    var p = document.createElement('p');
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = item.Url;
    $(a).append(item.Title);
    $(p).append(item.Description);
    $('#results').append(a, p);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <label for="searchTerm">Search: </label>
    <input id="searchTerm" type="text"/>
    <button id="searchButton">Search</button>

    <div id="results">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```